Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Web'
I am currently writing unit tests for a WCF application. In the implementation of the ServiceContract, It returns a 401 response in case of wrong credentials. See code below:
public GenericResponse<string> GetAuthenticationToken()
{
    try
    {
        var authToken = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var token = await _authenticationService.AuthenticationUser();
            return token;
        });

        return new GenericResponse<string>()
        {
            ErrorMessage = string.Empty,
            HasError = false,
            ResponseObject = authToken.Result
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (ex.InnerException.Message.StartsWith("Invalid credentials passed"))
    {
        // Set the HTTP status code
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;

        return new GenericResponse<string>
        {
            HasError = true,
            ErrorMessage = "Invalid Credentials",
            ResponseObject = ex.InnerException.Message
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var fault = new GenericErrorResponse
        {
            ErrorMessage = $"An unknown error occured while authenticating",
            ErrorCode = 500,
            Details = $"An error occured while getting authentication token: {ex.Message}. {ex.InnerException?.Message ?? string.Empty}"
        };

        // Throw FaultException with custom fault
        throw new FaultException<GenericErrorResponse>(fault, new FaultReason(fault.ErrorMessage));
    }
}

I returns a 401 if invalid credentials are passed and this works fine when I run the service. However, the problem arises when writing unit tests for this class/method.
 [TestMethod]
 public void GetAuthenticationToken()
 {
     mockAuthService.Setup(i => i.AuthenticationUser())
         .Returns(() => Task.Run(() => VALID_TOKEN));

     var expectedResponse = new GenericResponse<string>()
     {
         ErrorMessage = string.Empty,
         HasError = false,
         ResponseObject = VALID_TOKEN
     };

     var awsWcfFileStorageService = new AwsWcfFileStorageService(mockAuthService.Object,
        mockS3FileService.Object);

     var actualResponse = awsWcfFileStorageService.GetAuthenticationToken();

     actualResponse.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedResponse);
 }

When I run the unit test, I get the following exception error
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.'

The stackTrace for this exception is as follows:
   at email_wcf_service.AwsWcfFileStorageService.GetAuthenticationToken() in D:\Projects\file-storage-windows-service\file-storage-wcf-service\FileStorageService.cs:line 89
   at file_storage_wcf_service.Tests.FileStorageServiceTests.GetAuthenticationToken() in D:\Projects\file-storage-windows-service\file-storage-wcf-service.Tests\AwsWcfFileStorageServiceTests.cs:line 139
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithNoArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr)

I tried to match the versions but it still did not help

The problem is probably caused by
var actualResponse = awsWcfFileStorageService.GetAuthenticationToken();
It didn't call "System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext" correctly and successfully.
First of all, I suggest that you check whether the program project environment of the test environment is consistent with the service. You'll definitely need a tester to access this test service code. But you mentioned in the question that you have gone and tried to check the version. So I think it could be an issue with the framework itself as well. There are currently a number of Sistems and Seversemmore bags in Cole that can be installed, and in McCden it is said to work fine. However, it is not actually possible to quote and will give the above error message.
Secondly, I think the reason may be that you are not using HTTP requests when you are testing. However, System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext requires an HTTP request, which may cause it to fail to be initialized and may not load correctly.
